# How to vertically align elements in <li>

Tags: html, css

I want to vertically middle the elements in the "li" but vertical-align: middle; command does not work. Display:table; and Display: table-cell; I tried commands like. I thought about importing the contents as a block but still didn't work. I centered it horizontally but not vertically. I would be glad if you help me.

```css
.navigation {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 75px;
    background: #222327;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.navigation ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    width: 750px;
}
.navigation ul li {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 150px;
    height: 75px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        <title>Astronomical Observers</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="title_logo_transparent.png">
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="navigation">
          <ul>
              <li class="nav_list">
                 <a class="nav_icon" href="#">
                    <span>
                          <ion-icon name="home-outline"></ion-icon>
                    </span>
                 </a>
                 <a class="nav_text" href="#">Home Page</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav_list">
                   <a href="#">
                     <span>
                      <ion-icon name="newspaper"></ion-icon>
                     </span>
                     <span class="text">News</span>
                    </a>
                 </li>
           </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: remove height from .navigation ul li

Answer (score 0):

Define the parent with`display: table`

and the element itself with `vertical-align: middle` and `display: table-cell`.